# Placement of footnotes text inside boxes or sidebars

Tags: footnotes

I'm wondering about footnote placement in a nonfiction book that has both ordinary running text and boxed text (like sidebars). The boxed text consists of short paragraphs that are set apart from the running text and have a distinct design. Both the running text and the boxed text have footnotes. Should footnotes to boxed text appear within the box, or should they be included at the bottom of the page of running text with all the other footnotes? If each box contains its own footnotes, does the numbering start over at 1 in each box, or should symbols be used instead?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there **is** a real standard for this - it's up to you as the document designer to determine: for me, I'd add them to the *overall footnotes*, both for consistency and simplicity, and that also helps you avoid the re-numbering issue.